# Expose List<> in asmx service

Tags: c#, asmx, generic-list

Can I expose a `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` from a asmx service.
I tried it but the reference class generated at client have converted it as Arrary[].

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the option in update service reference?

[image: Update service reference]

You can set this by right mouse clicking on your service located in the Service References folder, then select Configure Service Reference.

And may you have set that option already and your still getting back an array then may i suggest to look here
http://johnnblade.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/service-reference-returns-array-t-instead-of-listt/

---

[image: Service Reference]

Comment: I don't have, Add Service Reference in my project, but I have add WebReference. And I don't get these settings while adding service web reference.

Comment: Choose to add a service reference, right mouse click on your project

Comment: I am using .net 2.0, Does it make any difference.

Comment: I tried so hard, but in the end it doesn't matter :). I am still not getting Add service reference in my project(even on right clicking). I am getting add web reference, and it doesn't have the configure window as you mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added an image, so you dont have the option to add a service reference ?